# Hibernate database schema validation fails for H2 database when entity contains UUID

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

For a **H2 database schema** mapping to an **entity with a UUID**, the **Hibernate ddl validation fails** with the **exception**:

> Root cause: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
>   Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [testuuid]
>   in table [`TEST`.`dummy`]; found [varbinary (Types#VARBINARY)], but
>   expecting [binary (Types#BINARY)]

Setup:

- Hibernate 5.2.9.Final
- H2 1.4.194

further hibernate settings:

- hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
- Database dialect is not set explicitly.

The H2 DDL is initially generated with hibernate resulting in the **UUID being represented by 'binary'** in the H2 database schema.

*Disabling the validation works, but is not an option.*

**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **root cause** is that in the **H2 database some data types are synonym**, but [hibernate currently does not handle this fact](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9835).

There is [another stackoverflow question targeting a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907617) with H2 returning a synonym type instead of the expected one.

A [workaround is proposed in the related hibernate bugtracker ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9835). Just implement a **custom hibernate H2 dialect** which may look like this:

```
package your.pckg.name;

import java.sql.Types;
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;

public class H2DialectCustom extends H2Dialect {

    public H2DialectCustom() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "varbinary");
    }

}
```

and *register it in your hibernate/JPA settings*:

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = your.pckg.name.H2DialectCustom

Answer (score 6):

I complete agree with the [answer given by AntiTiming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43093800/3447566).

Another possible workaround is to specify the column definition explicitly on the UUID property of the JPA entity:

```
public class Entity {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "varbinary not null")
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

}
```

Comment: You saved my day! This works for me in a non-spring context! (R3 Corda)

Comment: It was helpful for me too while upgrading to Corda 4.8. Thanks