# Schema Validation Error for custom queryable states using `UUID` as a column

Tags: persistence, corda

I have defined a custom `QueryableState` whose persistent counterpart is defined by the code below

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract_course_class_state")
data class PersistentCourseClass(
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var courseId: UUID? = null
): PersistentState()
```

The problem is the node cannot startup with the following error:

```
[ERROR] 14:07:12+0800 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup: Incompatible schema change detected. Please run schema migration scripts (node with sub-command run-migration-scripts). Reason: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [courseId] in table [contract_course_class_state]; found [varbinary (Types#VARBINARY)], but expecting [binary (Types#BINARY)]
```

I have already run migration scripts as suggested but the problem still occurs. How can I resolve this?

Corda version: 4.8

Comment: This will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337943/3519732.

Comment: I've configured a custom H2Dialect for Hibernate as suggested by subclassing. But the above problem still occurs. I inspect the cordapp jars in the node directory and can find the `hibernate.properties` file. So I suspect Corda will configure hibernate itself and [I was right](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.6/enterprise/node/setup/corda-configuration-fields.html#database). But it still won't start up due to `[Error(s) while parsing node configuration: - for path: "database.hibernateDialect": Unknown property 'hibernateDialect'`. The doc is for Corda Enterprise though.

Comment: So the question now effective becomes "how to configure Hibernate in Corda OS?"

Comment: By the way, if I use the second method, I get this error during testing: `... Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "8a0b9e79-8ffb-406d-9def-89cfae17ff29"; SQL statement:
insert into contract_course_state (title, output_index, transaction_id) values (?, ?, ?) -- (?1, ?2, ?3) ...`